# Time sent on email is wrong

Tags: linux, email

I'm having trouble with the time on emails sent through mail.utils. Thunderbird shows the date sent for emails generated with `mail` as 24 hours ahead of the actual date sent.

To show the difference in headers, I sent 2 emails from the command line. One was directly through mail and the other through php.

```
mike@wilma:/etc/mail$ echo "Test" | mail -a "X-datesent:$(date +'%H:%M:%S')" -s 'CLI test' mike@mike-mac.net
mike@wilma:/etc/mail$ php -r 'mail("mike@mike-mac.net", "PHP test", "test", "X-datesent:" . date("H:i:s")) ;'
```

Headers for the email generated by `mail` are

```
Return-Path: <mike@mike-mac.gen.nz>
X-Original-To: mike@mike-mac.net
Delivered-To: mike@mike-mac.net
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.mike-mac.gen.nz (Postfix) with ESMTP id CD9DA2BC003C
    for <mike@mike-mac.net>; Tue, 10 Oct 2023 01:16:31 +1300 (NZDT)
Received: from mail.mike-mac.gen.nz ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (wilma.mike-mac.gen.nz [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id TiMiAEKqCXmS for <mike@mike-mac.net>;
    Tue, 10 Oct 2023 01:16:31 +1300 (NZDT)
Received: by mail.mike-mac.gen.nz (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id B2D082BC003D; Tue, 10 Oct 2023 01:16:30 +1300 (NZDT)
X-datesent: 01:16:30
Subject: CLI test
To: <mike@mike-mac.net>
User-Agent: mail (GNU Mailutils 3.14)
Date: Tue, 10 Oct 2023 01:16:30 -1100
Message-Id: <20231009121631.B2D082BC003D@mail.mike-mac.gen.nz>
From: Mike McIntyre <mike@wilma.mike-mac.gen.nz>
```

Headers from the email generated with PHP are

```
Return-Path: <mike@mike-mac.gen.nz>
X-Original-To: mike@mike-mac.net
Delivered-To: mike@mike-mac.net
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mail.mike-mac.gen.nz (Postfix) with ESMTP id ECCD12BC003C
    for <mike@mike-mac.net>; Tue, 10 Oct 2023 01:16:38 +1300 (NZDT)
Received: from mail.mike-mac.gen.nz ([127.0.0.1])
    by localhost (wilma.mike-mac.gen.nz [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
    with ESMTP id WrHE2C9CcL7b for <mike@mike-mac.net>;
    Tue, 10 Oct 2023 01:16:38 +1300 (NZDT)
Received: by mail.mike-mac.gen.nz (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id D60532BC003D; Tue, 10 Oct 2023 01:16:38 +1300 (NZDT)
To: mike@mike-mac.net
Subject: PHP test
X-datesent:01:16:38
Message-Id: <20231009121638.D60532BC003D@mail.mike-mac.gen.nz>
Date: Tue, 10 Oct 2023 01:16:38 +1300 (NZDT)
From: Mike McIntyre <mike@mike-mac.gen.nz>
```

The only difference I can see is in the `Date:` header

Tracing `mail` back to source and getting the version

```
mike@wilma:/etc/mail$ which mail
/usr/bin/mail
mike@wilma:/etc/mail$ file /usr/bin/mail
/usr/bin/mail: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/mail
mike@wilma:/etc/mail$ file /etc/alternatives/mail
/etc/alternatives/mail: symbolic link to /usr/bin/mail.mailutils
mike@wilma:/etc/mail$ file /usr/bin/mail.mailutils
/usr/bin/mail.mailutils: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=f7eaf662d3c899c2ea6118af56f4709a9a1fae74, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

mike@wilma:/etc/mail$ mail --version
mail (GNU Mailutils) 3.14
Copyright (C) 2007-2022 Free Software Foundation, inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Time zone information is

```
mike@wilma:/etc/mail$ timedatectl
               Local time: Tue 2023-10-10 01:28:02 NZDT
           Universal time: Mon 2023-10-09 12:28:02 UTC
                 RTC time: Mon 2023-10-09 12:28:02
                Time zone: Pacific/Auckland (NZDT, +1300)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

I'm using postfix and dovecot, if that's of any help.

Cheers

Mike

edit #1

```
mike@wilma:~$ cat /etc/sysconfing/clock
cat: /etc/sysconfing/clock: No such file or directory
mike@wilma:~$ ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Jun  5 15:51 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Pacific/Auckland
```

edit #2
I added the following line to crontab

```
*/5 * * * * echo "testing"
```

The generated emails have the correct time, as do error emails generated by crontab.

Without knowing how crontab generates emails, I'm thinking that this narrows the problem down to email generated directly through `/usr/bin/mail.mailutils`.

edit #3
Tried forcing a TZ value with this

```
mike@wilma:~$ cat /etc/profile.d/mailutils-date.sh 
# this is an attempt to fix the Date field in emails generated by mail.utils
if [ -z "${TZ}" ]
then
 TZ=`cat /etc/timezone`
 export TZ
fi
### after reboot ###
mike@wilma:~$ echo $TZ
Pacific/Auckland
```

Comment: Do you have a $TZ environment variable?

Comment: ```mike@wilma:~$ echo "${TZ:-Nothing there}"```

Nothing there

Comment: (1) Some BIOS have time-zone information, check if yours has it. (2) Add to your post the contents of `/etc/sysconfing/clock` and the output of `ls -l /etc/localtime`.

Comment: Output added as requested. No timezone in bios.

Comment: Try to set "RTC in local TZ" (time standard of the hardware clock) to "yes" with the command `timedatectl set-local-rtc 1`. To return the current setting use `0`.

Comment: Tried that, no change to the date for the CLI email

Comment: Did you reboot? (That's just about my last attempt...)

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for your attempts, greatly appreciated. I'm not using CLI mail to send outside my LAN so I can live with it. Anything that needs to go outside the LAN can be pushed through PHP mail()